# Head tag <head> </head> to articles on an Oculus 3.3.3 Joomla Template

Tags: head

i, I want to know how to add a Head tag    to articles on an Oculus 3.3.3 Joomla Template this is ti add it to the index.php of my hosting

Comment: <head></head> tag has to be added to template index.php under: /templates/your_template/index.php. If you want to do something else please try to be more specific.

Comment: Ok the issue is that my articles dont have a head tag i.e <head></head>

Comment: Ok the issue is that my articles dont have a head tag i.e <head></head> <body> <content> what is the right head tag to include or add in the index.php my site is www.imperiosports.com and its a Oculus 3.3.3 Joomla Template i need instructions and what would be the head tag code to add to the index.php?

Comment: There is a <head><title></title></head> inside <body> section that is wrong. Try disabling 3rd party plugins that you are using to check if the problem is getting solved and try to change template to the joomla default to see if <title> appear in the <head> section.

Comment: no i put put the joomla template to default and nothing happened what would be the suggestion? what to do my article images when shared on facebook, it shares the wrong image, sometimes an option to select up to three images on a thumbnail format.and always the wrong image.

Comment: There may be something misconfigured to miss the <title> tag. Please try to add a title to the menu item to see if it gets displayed.

Comment: As for the facebook image, you have to check if og:image tag has the correct path. If not you have to check which component / plugin adds that tag in order to correct it.

Comment: so Emmanuel The solution for this problem would be to add the head tag to the index.php and therefore fixing the problem about facebook sharing wrong image or og.image  what would be the correct paht and what would be the plugin that adds the tags?

Comment: og tags are not being added by default in joomla. You have to check the 3rd party components / plugins that you have installed and find which one has the problem.

Comment: Hi I did some research and found this plugin please tell me if will do the job tofix the og-image?  http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/open-graph/17810

Comment: and also these are some codes to add where and which one? this is a link about og  http://ogp.me

Comment: Man this a mess what the heck? look at this how in the world can i fix this og matter  went to faceboo debugger and found this out----Scrape Information
Time Scraped 2 seconds ago
Response Code 206
Fetched URL http://www.imperiosports.com/
Canonical URL http://www.imperiosports.com/
Warning
Errors That Must Be Fixed

Comment: Errors That Must Be Fixed
Meta Tags In Body Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.
Facebook CDN not allowed for og:image. Provided og:image url, https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/1975134_10152261404934397_5845840724451747312_n.jpg, is disallowed